# Replace text between single quotes in Linux

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to find and replace "option wmm '0'" with "option wmm '1'" from a file /etc/config/wireless.

I'm currently using grep -rl 'option wmm' /etc/config/wireless | xargs sed -i 's/0/1/g' but it is changing all '0' to '1' like the 'radio0'.

Here is a sample output of the file

```
config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'test'
    option network 'WLAN2'
    option encryption 'psk'
    option wmm '0'
    option wpa_group_rekey '1200'
    option key 'Lp0IRP477vx6DjtVJ0Xb'
    option disabled '1'
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be using `s/'0'/'1'/` (put the command inside double-quotes `"` instead of simple quotes `'`)

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
 sed "/option wmm '0'/s/0/1/" file
```